# Qt crashes when I try to execute any program

Tags: c++, qt, crash

I've looked for an answer during a few days and I haven't found anything similar anywhere;

I downloaded Qt from the official website, installed it and apparently compiling is fine. But whenever I try to execute (Ctrl+R) any app, even the basic one which only displays a window or widget, QtCreator itself crashes. No error message, nothing, just crashing.

I've tried to redownload and reinstall it a few times with different settings, but nothing will do.

I'm running QtCreator on Windows 7 64 bits. I'll try on my laptop which is also running windows and will update if I find anything.

Any help would be appreciated, I need to start a project as soon as possible. I'm relatively new to QT and if you need info on anything just ask me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency walker, http://www.dependencywalker.com/

and post any missing dependencies.  It is possible some install targets or options are missing from when you installed QtCreator, which can be resolved with the maintenance tool in the same directory you installed Qt.

Also, are you using the Visual Studio compiler(must have Visual Studio installed separately, and mark the option during install), or the Ming compiler(2 options checked during install or maintenance)?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your antivirus is locking it, I had a similar issue time ago and it was due to antivirus (Avast specifically). Disable antivirus' realtime shields and try to execute a basic app.

Answer (score -1):

It is necessary to use QtCreator? I use QtDesigner snd VS2013 and things go very well. :)

check this thread [Qt Creator Plain C++ Project won't run/debug...](http://Qt%20Creator%20Plain%20C++%20Project%20won't%20run/debug...) and this [C++ - QtCreator doesn't show any output](http://C++%20-%20QtCreator%20doesn't%20show%20any%20output)